# Does Instruments (ObjectAlloc/Leaks) require the simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, instruments

This may be a very stupid question so I apologize in advance. It seems that Instruments only works for me when using the iPhone Simulator. Is there something special to getting it working when tethering the application to the iPhone? Or is that even possible? I launch the application the normal way through the Run->Start with performace tool, etc., then see it's installing the app to my provisioned iPhone, then it launches Instruments but nothing. I thought since it's connected via USB it would be but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My device worked with Instruments after following these steps:

1. Unplug the iPhone.
2. In XCode, open the Organizer.
3. Delete the device.
4. Plug device in.
5. Answer yes when asked if you want to use device for development.

Comment: I'm sad that you only got 1 point for this, I'm going to go to some of your answers and vote you up! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not asked the question in step 5 and i'm still unable to get it to work; any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Start Instruments first, while your iPhone is already tethered.  Choose which one you want and then pick the app from the popup menu and "record".

Answer (score 0):

Run the application on the iPhone in debug mode via XCode. You cannot monitor an application run directly on the device in Instruments. Connect your device to your Mac, select Device as the target instead of Simulator and then in the Run menu, select "Start with Performance Tool"

Answer (score -1):

It works with the device, in XCode, go to the top bar, and i think it's inside "build" (don't have a mac infront of me so sorry for the vague position) in there you select "run application with performance tool" (something like that) and that will start a new Instruments' session connected to the hardware. You can't (as far as I know) just connect directly from Instruments to the device, it needs to be through XCode.

Comment: That's what I did but it didn't work for me. Back to the drawing board.