# iPhone memory leaks with store kit

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, storekit

I am trying to develop an application which uses storekit api. The document (Store Kit guide) suggests that the api will not work on a simulator. I found out that memory leaks will not be able to work on a device. I was wondering if any one can tell me how to check for memory leaks while using a store kit api on a project?
How is it possible?

Comment: I’m sorry to have to inform you that memory leaks indeed do work on the device ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use instruments with the device to find memory leaks. See [Does Instruments (ObjectAlloc/Leaks) require the simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379983/does-instruments-objectalloc-leaks-require-the-simulator)