# XCode instruments not reporting any data

Tags: xcode, ipad, debugging, instruments

I'm trying to debug in XCode using the instruments but most of them are not showing any data.  I tried this from my home machine and it worked fine, but on my work iMac the following instruments report no data at all:

- Activity Monitor
- Allocations
- Memory Monitor

The Leaks instrument seems to be working fine.

I am developing an iPad app and am trying to run the instruments with the simulator.

XCode version 3.2.3 64-bit

Xcode IDE: 1688.0

Xcode Core: 1691.0

ToolSupport: 1591.0

Instruments Version 2.7 (2529)

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: EDIT: Running from the device works fine.  The issue is only when running on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  It looks like cmd-tabbing back and forth between the Xcode and Instruments window triggers the simulator to start up:

[Instruments 4.1 unresponsive to projects launched from Xcode 4.1 until pressing Cmd-Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224665/instruments-4-1-unresponsive-to-projects-launched-from-xcode-4-1-until-pressing)

Answer (score 3):

What helped me is rebooting the iPad I was testing on. I've tried other tricks, this is the simplest and quickest one .)

Z.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in debug or release mode? What are your target's debug settings (ie, level of debug symbols, optimization level, strip status, etc.)? You'll need to be in debug mode and for your target's debug configuration information, you'll want default or all debugging symbols, no optimization, and no strip.

Comment: running in debug mode with symbols.  I tried with a clean new project and got the same results.  Also the instruments work if I run it from the device as opposed to the simulator.

Comment: Seems to be the opposite problem but possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379983/does-instruments-objectalloc-leaks-require-the-simulator

Comment: If re-installing the device worked for that problem, then the mirrored solution for me would be to re-install the SDK. I was afraid of that.  I don't have time to do this now and I can work from the device so I can't confirm it.  I also want to add that someone else at my company was having the exact same issue that I am having.