# XCode 3.2.4 buggy debugger?

Tags: xcode, debugging

i'm developing iPhone apps. Yesterday i updated leopard to snow leopard. Alongside i made the jump from `XCode 3.1.4` to `3.2.4`

I was always quite happy with `XCode` - working most of the time under windows, I really appreciate how well the `XCode toolchain` works together.

however - i'm not happy with `3.2.4` at all. i experience a lot of flaws, mainly with debugging. When an error arises, the debugger often stops at another place than the actual error happened. Sometimes the debugger does not trap into breakpoints at all and i get after some time a `Error from Debugger: mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack` - whatever that means. And also I get invisible breakpoints which i can't remove anymore.

Does anyone experience similar things with `XCode 3.2.4`? if so, which is the newest release that works well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is to do with level of debug symbols or some compiler optimization (which shouldn't be applied in debug builds). Maybe the [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737875/xcode-instruments-not-reporting-any-data/3737889#3737889) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Also try a complete clean (delete the build folder, remove the app from the device/simulator) & rebuild. Ensure you're working with the Debug configuration.