# Instruments 4.1 unresponsive to projects launched from Xcode 4.1 until pressing Cmd-Tab

Tags: xcode, xcode4, instruments, xcode-instruments

If I open Instruments and select a standard application (e.g. Mail or MS Word) it has no issue. 
If I am in Xcode and I go to **Product > Profile** (or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>), it launches Instruments, allows me to select a template, and loads the standard screen. Then the downward arrow starts tracing to the right as it should, and the iOS simulator launches the program. However, nothing is plotted in Instruments. It shows no changes to anything no matter what the app is doing. I can't click anything in Instruments: no menu's, can't stop recording, can't open tabs, etc.

I randomly discovered that if I hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Instruments will start behaving normally. This seems really strange to me. Either it's a bug or it's a hole in my knowledge about how to operate Instruments.

Comment: Wow, thanks for bringing this up. I can deal with tabbing between windows if that gets instruments to work.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Xcode 4.2.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using XCode 4.2.1 and most of the instruments refuse to record any data no matter what I do.

Comment: known in 4.1, seems resolved for me in 4.3. Be patient when instruments starts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange bug is fixed in XCode 4.2!
The problem was the hidden password dialog, so sometime it works and sometimes not. 
One of possible solutions was:

1. Run Instruments
2. Cmd Tab to Xcode covering the instruments. Cycle and hide messages until password dialog is found.
3. Close Xcode.

PS: I know it is a few years to late for the answer, I was just looking for unanswered questions. Just check as answered - > it's good for both of us. )